# How to create a polyline between the source and destination using google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to show the path between the source and destination and also trying to move an icon in this given path.

I was able to move an icon from the source and destination but the path is getting revealed only when the icon is moving.

I want the whole path to be shown at the beginning itself.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Animated route</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
  html, body, #map {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px
  }
 </style>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
 <script>
        
  function initialize() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
     center: {lat: 17.416483, lng: 78.513592},
     zoom: 13,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });
   
   getDirections(map);
  }

  function moveMarker(map, marker, latlng) {
   marker.setPosition(latlng);
   map.panTo(latlng);
  }

  function autoRefresh(map, pathCoords) {
   var i, route, marker;
   
   route = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    geodesic : true,
    strokeColor: 'blue',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    editable: false,
    map:map
   });
   
   marker=new google.maps.Marker({map:map, icon:"truck.png"});

   for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {    
    setTimeout(function(coords) {
     route.getPath().push(coords);
     moveMarker(map, marker, coords);
    }, 2000 * i, pathCoords[i]);
   }
  }
  
  function getDirections(map) {
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
   
   var start = new google.maps.LatLng(17.416483, 78.513592);
   var end = new google.maps.LatLng(17.424643, 78.645126);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:   end,
          map: map,
         
        });
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:  start ,
          map: map,
         icon:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png"
        });


   var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
   };
   directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     autoRefresh(map, result.routes[0].overview_path);
    }
   });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something like [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html)?

Comment: @geocodezip....yes, exactly but I don't want to copy the entire code of what you have shown, could you please let me know just the block of code which is used to show the path?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to display the complete route is to use the [google.maps.DirectionRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DisplayingResults), if you don't want it's markers, use the `suppressMarkers: true` option in its constructor, you can style the polyline as well.

```
// create the directionsDisplay reference
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true
  });
  // add it to the map
  getDirections(map);
```

then use it to display the route:

```
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
      autoRefresh(map, result.routes[0].overview_path);
    }
  });
```

**code snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Animated route</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
  <script>
    var directionsDisplay;

    function initialize() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: {
          lat: 17.416483,
          lng: 78.513592
        },
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map,
        suppressMarkers: true
      });
      getDirections(map);
    }

    function moveMarker(map, marker, latlng) {
      marker.setPosition(latlng);
      map.panTo(latlng);
    }

    function autoRefresh(map, pathCoords) {
      var i, route, marker;

      route = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: 'blue',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        editable: false,
        map: map
      });

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: pinSymbol("blue")
      });

      for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(coords) {
          route.getPath().push(coords);
          moveMarker(map, marker, coords);
        }, 2000 * i, pathCoords[i]);
      }
    }

    function getDirections(map) {
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      var start = new google.maps.LatLng(17.416483, 78.513592);
      var end = new google.maps.LatLng(17.424643, 78.645126);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: end,
        map: map,

      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: start,
        map: map,
        icon: pinSymbol("red")
      });


      var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
          autoRefresh(map, result.routes[0].overview_path);
        }
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    function pinSymbol(color) {
      return {
        path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        scale: 1
      };
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```